# securing a wcf with https

Tags: wcf, https

I hosted a WCF .svc file in IIS 6.0 under a virtual directory secured with https. When requesting the wsdl through my browser I get a http 400 error. Here's a chunk of my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>  
    <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="TransportSecurity">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
              </security>
          </binding>     
  </basicHttpBinding>     
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="AuthWorkStation_Extranet.App_Code.AwsService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">       
    <endpoint name="" address="https://extlpo01.srr.fr/Sphinx/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="AuthWorkStation_Extranet.App_Code.IAwsService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
         <serviceCertificate storeName="Root" findValue="CA_SRR_DISTRIB" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials> 
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

anyone knows what's wrong with my setup ?

Comment: Sorry, for HTTPS with BasicHttp you need Transport security mode with Windows, Basic, or None clientCredentialType

Comment: I enabled Windows authentication as well as the Basic one.

Comment: Can you leave just Anonumous?

Comment: I unchecked Windows and Basic authentication. Still http 400 showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want HTTPS, you need to update your web.config.  Change the following:

```
<bindings>   
  <basicHttpBinding> 
    <binding name="TransportSecurity"> 
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"> 
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/> 
      </security> 
    </binding>      
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
```

To:

```
<bindings>   
  <basicHttpBinding> 
    <binding name="TransportSecurity"> 
      <security mode="Transport"> 
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/> 
      </security> 
    </binding>      
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
```

Comment: Do you have client certificates enabled for the site?  For SSL, the client certificate setting in IIS should be 'Ignore'

Comment: After removing these two lines: <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
My sll error disapeared but I'm now back to the http 400 bad request error

Comment: So I finnaly found out the right setting for my WCF. I use Transport security mode, Certificate clientCredentialType. I had to remove the mex endpoint and to remove the serviceDebug tag. Also I emptied the address parameter of the service endpoint.